# Covariance of multiples of a Random variable

Tags: covariance

we have a random variable W $\sim$ N(0,1) and Z${}_{t}$=tW  for t $\in$ $\mathrm{R}$

What is Cov(Z${}_{t1}$,Z${}_{t2}$)  for t1, t2 $\in$ $\mathrm{R}$?

Comment: Is this question related to coursework? In which case a `self-study` tag would be appropriate, as well reading the recommended way to approach such questions.

Comment: The notation is also artificially clumsy. What is wrong with simply asking $\text{Cov}(aW, bW)$ for real parameters $a$ and $b$. How does the restriction to integers make things any different? And in what way does the Normality assumption make any binding difference on the answer?

Comment: thanks wolfies.  you are right.  your question clarified the problem and I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on  peers postings in the comments section I figured out the answer:

Cov(Z${}_{t1}$,Z${}_{t2}$)  = Cov(aW,bW)  = ab

since W $\sim$ N(0,1)

Thanks.